# Recorrer un objeto completo con recursión para encontrar un valor especificado

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, recursión

Hola compañeros nuevamente en el afán de aprender recursividad estoy con un ejercicio que he resuelto a medias ya que no me recorre el objeto completo. El contexto es el siguiente:

**Este es el objeto en cuestión**

```
let obj = {
  school: {
    hogwarts: {
      headmaster: {
        name: {
          first: "Albus",
          last: "Dumbledore",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prop1:5,
  prop2:6
};
```

**Y este es el enunciado.**

Dado un objeto con objetos anidados utilizar la recursión para crear una función que devuelva true o false dependiendo si el objeto tiene o no el valor pasado por parámetro.

Ya realice el código para recorrer y encontrar el valor que se le esta pasando por parámetro pero solo recorre hasta cuando entra en los objetos anidados y si no encuentra el valor allí se sale y me regresa false ya que no sigue recorriendo los elementos del primer nivel de anidación.
**Ejemplificando, este es mi codigo:**

```
const isThere = function (obj, value){
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop] === value) {
      return true;
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
      obj = obj[prop];
      return isThere(obj, value);
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

cuando hago las siguientes llamadas funciona bien

```
isThere(obj, "Albus");
isThere(obj, "headmaster")
```

pero cuando hago esta

```
isThere(obj, 6);
```

deberia regresar true pero encambio regresa false. ¿ que debo hacer ?

Comment: Tú código también revisa las llaves de los objetos? Es decir, en el caso de `isThere(obj, "headmaster")` el comportamiento esperado es que devuelva `false` o `true`?

Comment: @FranAcuna en ese caso el comportamiento esperado es false ya que 'headmaster ' no es un valor sino una clave por lo que ese valor no lo encuentra.

Comment: Entiendo, en este caso voy a editar mi respuesta y actualizarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos cosas que te están impidiendo lograr el resultado esperado, voy a asumir que también quieres buscar entre los nombres de las llaves de los objetos ( caso en el que `isThere(obj, "headmaster")` da como resultado `true` ).

1. El `return` que haces en tu invocación recursiva (`return isThere(obj, value);`) termina el ciclo `for` que recorre entre
   todos los elementos, es decir, nunca recorres un elemento más allá
   de `school`, te recomiendo solo hacer el `return` si el resultado de
   la función recursiva es `true`, de esta manera en caso de no haber
   encontrado un resultado no harás un `return false` que detendría la
   ejecución de tu ciclo `for`.
2. Si quieres buscar también entre las llaves de los objetos (como es el caso de headmaster) te recomiendo que uses [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) para poder obtener los dos valores en cada iteración (llave y valor) y hacer las comparaciones respectivas.

Tomando esto en cuenta, tu código se vería así:

```js
let obj = {
  school: {
    hogwarts: {
      headmaster: {
        name: {
          first: "Albus",
          last: "Dumbledore",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prop1:5,
  prop2:6
};

const isThere = function (obj, target){
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (value === target || key === target) {
      return true;
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      const result = isThere(value, target);
      if(result){return true;}
    }
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(isThere(obj, "Albus"));
console.log(isThere(obj, "headmaster"));
console.log(isThere(obj, 6));
console.log(isThere(obj, "perro"));
```

### UPDATE

Puedes ignorar el segundo punto ya que el comportamiento esperado no busca entre las llaves de los objetos:

```js
let obj = {
  school: {
    hogwarts: {
      headmaster: {
        name: {
          first: "Albus",
          last: "Dumbledore",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prop1: 5,
  prop2: 6
};

const isThere = function(obj, target) {
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    if (value === target) {
      return true;
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      if (isThere(value, target)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(isThere(obj, "Albus"));
console.log(isThere(obj, "headmaster"));
console.log(isThere(obj, 6));
console.log(isThere(obj, "perro"));
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona bien, ahora analizare bien tu respuesta.

Comment: Me podrías explicar como funciona las siguientes líneas
const result = isThere(value, target);
      if(result){return true;}

Comment: Claro, lo que estamos haciendo es condicionando el `return` para que solamente se ejecute en caso de que una de las invocaciones recursivas devuelve `true`. De esta manera si la función no encuentra el valor que se está buscando devuelve `false` porque llega al final de la función (hizo todas sus iteraciones, es decir, el `for` terminó) y por lo tanto el ciclo `for` de la función "padre" (la que hizo la invocación de la función recursiva) puede continuar buscando entre todos las demás propiedades del objeto.